# What is a more formal way of saying "get certifications"?

Tags: synonyms, formality

I would like to create a sentence, in which I express, that I have (successfully) gotten a few certifications, but I feel like this sounds too informal for a letter of application.

Has anyone got a better idea or is this way of saying it already appropriate?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what they are formally referred to as -- there are "Certifications" as such, and there are others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've '[qualified](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/qualify)' in something.

> 2.1 [WITH OBJECT] Officially recognize or establish (someone) as a practitioner of a particular profession or activity:

You are now '[certified](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/certify)' in that thing.

> 1.1 *chiefly British* Officially recognize as possessing certain qualifications or meeting certain standards:

You might even be '[accredited](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/accredit)' (or licensed or authorised) to do it.

> 2. (Of an official body) give authority or sanction to (someone or something) when recognized standards have been met:
> 3. Give official authorization for (someone, typically a diplomat or journalist) to be in a particular place or to hold a particular post:

Comment: So i would say "I became a certified ..." or "I have qualified as a ..."? Could i form a sentence like "Through becoming a a certified [something], I have [gotten some abilites]"?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. Sounds good.

Answer (score 0):

I would say acquire a certification

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Your answer would be improved with an explanation of why you suggest *acquire*, ideally with examples and/or a dictionary definition or other reference. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for guidance on submitting high quality answers on this site.